# Cannot assign value to variable by reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I would like to assign value to the variable IMLoginReq inside a ProtoBuf load function, but its not working, can anyone help?

```
var IMLoginReq;
protobuf.load("./pb/IM.Login.proto", (err, root) => {
    // Obtain a message type
    IMLoginReq = root.lookup("IM.Login.IMLoginReq");
    console.log(IMLoginReq);//<== is not undefined
});
console.log(IMLoginReq);//<== is undefined
```

Comment: Can I know what library u are using to make request?

Comment: I am using dcodeIO.protobuf to fetch my request definition proto, so the request is originally defined by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load()` method is asynchronous.  As such the console.log at the end will happen before the load finishes.  Instead of trying to treat this as procedural logic, which it is not, you should instead use the IMLoginReq inside the success method that you have.

Comment: This of course assumes that the load() is the jQuery method, though by your issue even if it is not, the load() is still appearing to be asynchronous.

Comment: This is the answer how it happened like that, very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are trying to call it before its loaded. You should have a callback function like success so it will be there.
You can also use promises by omitting the callback:

```
protobuf.load("awesome.proto")
    .then(function(root) {
       ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration